# Как получить ВСЕ твиты пользователя

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-api

я Авторизовался через Oauth и делаю запрос https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?screen_name=tutspluscode&count=200/
У пользователя твитов 15к, если я count ставлю больше чем 200,то опять же вертает 200, В доке стоит ограничение в 200 твитов. Можно как то получить больше твитов ?

Comment: И `since_id` не помогает?

Comment: А, и не должно помочь: `If the limit of Tweets has occured since the since_id, the since_id will be forced to the oldest ID available.`

Comment: Да, не помогло.

Comment: Да, зарубили они, когда-то ограничение в 3200 твитов было. Ну тогда только сюда или в что-то аналогичное: https://gnip.com/sources/twitter/

Answer (score 0):

купить доступ к расширенному api.
в 1.1 у них ограничение на 7 дней и, вроде, как раз 200 твитов

Comment: можете привести ссылку на исчтоник (страницу где указано ограничение и где показано как снять)